# How to update an MVC partial view with regular Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an Ajax form that updates the partial view it's in, but I need it to update a second partial view as well. I'd like to do this without merging them both into one view and updating that.
I think my best bet is to use a regular jQuery Ajax call on the form's `onsuccess`, but I don't know what parameters to use so I can just call a Controller Action that returns the partial to have it work.

My form is set up with

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateDateRange",
                                new { name = Model.Modules[i].Name },
                                new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = Model.Modules[i].Name.Replace(" ", "_") + "_module" }
                                ))
                            { [Input fields] }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your onSuccessmethod you can make another ajax call.

So for example in your OnSuccessMehtod call "MethodX"...which would do a ajax call and update a div on your page with returned result

```
var MethodX = function(id)
{
    $.get("ActionName?id=" + id, function (result) {
        $("#myAnotherdiv").html(result)
    }, 'html');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to ajax call you can send two partial view that you want with this helper:

```
public static class MvcHelpers
{
    public static string RenderPartialView(this Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            viewName = controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

        controller.ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

And in controller:

```
return Json(new { view1 = this.RenderPartialView(...), view2 = this.RenderPartialView(...) });
```

and in success you can get two partialView and replace them with old ones:

```
function success(data)
{
    $("someSelectorToSelectPartial1").html(data.view1);
    $("someSelectorToSelectPartial2").html(data.view2);
}
```